# Git: How to fork a project but still get patches from the parent fork?

Tags: git

Say I have two projects: Parent and Child. Child is a fork of Parent, so it has all the same code as Parent and additional edits and new files. Child will never be merged back into Parent. But Parent may still need to be developed and those changes should be sent to Child. What's the best way to do this with Git?.

I've done some looking around and I'm pretty sure that Submodules would not be good for this. Submodules are an external git repository parked at a directory in a different git repository, so that wouldn't work because a lot of Child is the same as Parent and should defer to changes pushed to Parent's master in the future.

I've been using remotes and then rebasing to get something that works like this, but the limitation is that the rebase is very manual. I have to know exactly what commit by message (because the refs change after rebase) to do the rebase for Child's master on to Parent's master form inside Child. I'd be looking for a way to have the same relationship with the rebasing, but for the actual act to be more automatic and less prone to mistake if I don't select the right starting commit to rebase Child's master onto Parent's master. I'm dead set on having the relationship be that Child knows Child and Parent, but Parent only knows Parent. If you know of a way to convert to the new system from what I've been using, I'd really appreciate it too.

### Update

I've been playing around with it and it seems that the only alternative to rebasing for my situation is `git merge -s ours` from Child. Rebasing presented the problem that commits to Child would constantly have changing refs because each rebase would re-build Child's git history. Merging ordinarily would not work because we don't want to set Child equal to Parent; Parent is just updating things that haven't been ceded to breaking changes in Child. Using the strategy `ours` (meaning Child's version) allows the projects to be developed separately, but keeping common changes originating in Parent is both projects. Child exists like a tumor, taking changes that are relied on by both projects, but having private changes that never get sent to Parent/master.

Comment: Do you want to pull all changes made to Parent into Child, or do you plan to pull in patches more selectively? If you plan to have all changes of Parent integrated into Child, maybe the LLVM talk "Living Downstream Without Drowning" could give you some inspiration. It talks about how to maintain downstream changes (the Child) while still keeping track of an upstream project (the Parent): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INCi9gOVMug and https://llvm.org/devmtg/2015-10/slides/RobinsonEdwards-LivingDownstreamWithoutDrowning.pdf

Comment: @StefanKempf all changes. But the changes should only overwrite what hasn't been changed by Child, so If you have two track files in both projects, once file1 get's change in child, child's version is always taken over parent when getting updates from parent. But, file2 will in that instance get updated.